# ASP.NET Core Web API, How can I access HttpContext in startup class

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to access `HttpContext` to get `RemoteIpAddress` and `User-Agent`, but within Startup.cs.

```
 public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            public IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor { get; }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("claveEncriptacion"));
                var ip = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
                var userAgent = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                //x.Audience = ip + "-" + userAgent;
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = true
                };
            });
```

With the previous code I have an error executing the project.

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'JobSiteMentorCore.Startup'.'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You cannot access `HttpContext` on startup because no request being made

Comment: In startup.cs I need to get RemoteIpAddress and User-Agent

Comment: What IP and user agent are you trying to get on startup? They are available during request only

Comment: IP and User-Agent to add x.Audience, because audience of token is dinamic

Answer (score 9):

According to the [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-startup-class) , only the following service types can be injected into the `Startup` constructor when using the Generic Host (IHostBuilder):

```
IWebHostEnvironment
IHostEnvironment
IConfiguration
```

So you cannot inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to `Startup` constructor.

However you can get DI resolved service in `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddScoped<IYourService, YourService>();

    // Build an intermediate service provider
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    // Resolve the services from the service provider
    var yourService = serviceProvider.GetService<IYourService>();

}
```

**But you can not get the `HttpContext` using `IHttpContextAccessor` similarly because `HttpContext` is null unless the code executed during any `HttpRequest`.** So you have to do your desired operation from any custom `middleware` in `Configure` method of the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public class YourCustomMiddleMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _requestDelegate;

    public YourCustomMiddleMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate)
    {
        _requestDelegate = requestDelegate;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

      // Your HttpContext related task is in here.

      await _requestDelegate(context);
    }
}
```

Then in the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseMiddleware(typeof(YourCustomMiddleMiddleware));
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code and I have null reference of _httpContextAccessor

Comment: Okay! Got the reason! I shall update the answer soon explaining the reason and way of overcoming your problem! Just let me know what do you want to get from HttpContext.

Comment: I need to create a token, and then this token is only called from the same browser and pc where it was created.
To make this differentiation, I used the IP and the user agent.

Comment: but I need to use it in ConfigureServices because the Token is validated inside

Comment: @vidgarga You should have been able to do the exact same operation from a custom middleware. The register the middleware in `Configure` method of the `Startup` class.

Comment: @TranvirArjel Can you write a little example?

Comment: @TranvirArjel okk, I can use context in Configure by using YourCustomMiddleMiddleware, but I need use context inside services.AddAuthentication

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a possible solution, using `middleware` to validate the token. 
I created a class `ValidationHandler`, and this class can use `HttpContext`.

```
public class ValidationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public string Issuer { get; }
        public string Scope { get; }

        public HasScopeRequirement(string scope, string issuer)
        {
            Scope = scope ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scope));
            Issuer = issuer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(issuer));
        }
    }


    public class ValidationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ValidationRequirement>
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public HasScopeHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasScopeRequirement requirement)
        {

            var ip = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
            var userAgent = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

            //context.Succeed(requirement);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Finally in the `Startup.cs` class it is necessary to add the following.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("read:messages", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("read:messages", "david")));
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you vidgarga.  I would upvote but I have a new account.  Your answer helped me on my project.  I'm coming from f# land so I am including my implementation for any fsharpers that need this solution.

```
type HasScopeHandler() =
    inherit AuthorizationHandler<HasScopeRequirement>()
        override __.HandleRequirementAsync(context, requirement) =
            let scopeClaimFromIssuer = Predicate<Claim>(fun (c: Claim) -> c.Type = "scope" && c.Issuer = requirement.Issuer)
            let userDoesNotHaveScopeClaim = not (context.User.HasClaim(scopeClaimFromIssuer))
            let isRequiredScope s = (s = requirement.Scope)
            let claimOrNull = context.User.FindFirst(scopeClaimFromIssuer)

            if (userDoesNotHaveScopeClaim) then
                Task.CompletedTask
            else
                match claimOrNull with
                | null -> Task.CompletedTask
                | claim ->
                    let scopes = claim.Value.Split(' ')
                    let hasRequiredScope = scopes.Any(fun s -> isRequiredScope s)
                    if (hasRequiredScope) then
                      context.Succeed(requirement)
                      Task.CompletedTask
                    else
                     Task.CompletedTask
```